# gateway timeout error while running cron job

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron

Can anyone please suggest any solution for **gateway timeout 504** error when running cron job on shared hosing. I have tried **sleep** function but it didn't work, I have following function for cron job -

```
public function checkOrderStatus(){
        $orders = Order::select('id')
                    ->whereNotIn('status', ['COMPLETED', 'CANCELLED', 'PARTIAL', 'REFUNDED'])
                    ->where('api_order_id', '!=', null)
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                    ->pluck('id')
                    ->toArray();

        $collection = collect($orders);

        $chunks = $collection->chunk(20);

        $request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
        foreach($chunks as $ids){
            foreach($ids as $id){
                $request->replace(['id' => $id]);
                $rep = $this->getOrderStatusFromAPI($request);
            }
            sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

**getOrderStatusFromAPI()** function calls 3rd party API to fetch some records. 
**checkOrderStatus()** function currently fetching around 300 records in each cron call. Please suggest any solution other than server upgrade. Thanks much!!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to your problem. If you're using NGINX with FastCGI try:

**Changes in php.ini**

Try raising max_execution_time setting in php.ini file (CentOS path is /etc/php.ini):

```
max_execution_time = 150
```

**Changes in PHP-FPM**

Try raising request_terminate_timeout setting in php.ini file (CentOS path is /etc/php-fpm.d):

```
request_terminate_timeout = 150
```

**Changes in Nginx Config**

Finally, add fastcgi_read_timeout variable inside our Nginx virtual host configuration:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Reload PHP-FPM and Nginx:

```
service php–fpm restart
service nginx restart
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but as I have mentioned - it is shared hosting so I can not make changes in config files.